# dropdown menu issue in mobile

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile, drop-down-menu

I have a problem with my menu in mobile mode. onClick it fadesOut. I want to keep this setting, however, I want it to do nothing, when one clicks on the dropdown part of the menu. 
here is link: http://jsfiddle.net/zLLzrs6b/3/
 appreciate your help!

also my html:

```
<nav id="nav-wrap">         
<a class="mobile-btn" href="#nav-wrap" title="Show navigation">Show Menu</a>
<a class="mobile-btn" href="#" title="Hide navigation">Hide Menu</a>         

<ul id="nav" class="nav">
<li><a class="smoothscroll mobile" href="#about">about</a></li>
<li><a class="smoothscroll mobile" href="#documents">blog</a></li>

<li class="nav-item"><a href="#">dropdown</a> 
<ul class="langop">
<li><a href="#">otion 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">otion 2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>  

</ul>
</nav>
```

css:

```
.langop 
{
display:none;
position: relative;
width:auto;
}

.nav-item:hover .langop {
display: block;
}
```

java:

```
var toggle_button = $("<a>", {                         
                    id: "toggle-btn", 
                    html : "Menu",
                    title: "Menu",
                    href : "#" } 
                    );
var nav_wrap = $('nav#nav-wrap')
var nav = $("ul#nav");  


nav_wrap.find('a.mobile-btn').remove(); 
nav_wrap.prepend(toggle_button); 

toggle_button.on("click", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
    nav.slideToggle("fast");     
});

if (toggle_button.is(':visible')) nav.addClass('mobile');
$(window).resize(function(){
if (toggle_button.is(':visible')) nav.addClass('mobile');
    else nav.removeClass('mobile');
});

$('ul#nav li a').on("click", function(){      
if (nav.hasClass('mobile')) nav.fadeOut('fast');      
});
```

Comment: Where is the variable `nav` being set? Are you sure it has a class of 'mobile'? You say it's not fading out. What _is_ happening then? Are you getting any exceptions in the console?

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues here, but the important ones are:

1. There is no "nav" variable being set.  I think you are confusing the $() selector with this "nav" variable.
2. There is no "mobile" class on your anchor elements.

You can avoid the `if` clause by simply specifying the anchor class right in the selector: `$(a.mobile)`  You can see a working version of it here: http://jsfiddle.net/zLLzrs6b/  I've added the "mobile" classes to your anchors and cleaned up the jQuery.

Comment: hello, ive added my whole code above. i want is, when one clicks on the language dropdown, the menu stays in place and doesn't fade out. could you have a look? i tried adding your code but it did not do the trick. thanks

Comment: All of my comments still apply.  You have undefined vars and bad markup.